# How prove this diophantine equation $(x^2-y)(y^2-x)=(x+y)^2$ have only three integer solution?

Tags: diophantine-equations

**HAPPY NEW YEAR To Everyone! (Now Beijing time  00:00 (2015))**

> Let $x,y$ are integer numbers,and such $xy\neq 0$,
>
> Find this diophantine equation all solution
> $$(x^2-y)(y^2-x)=(x+y)^2$$

I use Wolf found this equation only have two  nonzero integer solution $(x,y)=(-1,1),(-1,-1)$,see [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%5E2-b%29%28b%5E2-a%29%3D%28a%2Bb%29%5E2)
$$\Longleftrightarrow x^3+y^3+x^2+y^2=xy(xy-1)$$
But How prove it?

and I found sometimes,and my problem almost similar with 2012 IMO shortlist:[2012 IMO shortlist](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3160606&sid=1d528caee0ab75e89854293d637b2405#p3160606)

Comment: The equation in the title is different from the one in the post. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Oh,Sorry,I havd edit it

Comment: Let $P=xy,S=x+y$, then your equation is $P^2+P(1+3S)-S^2-S^3=0$, a quadratic whose discriminant is $1+6S+13S^2+4S^3$

Comment: if we say $1+6S+13S^2+4S^3$ is square numbers,But then maybe is ugly?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: At least, $S>-3$.

Comment: What about $(x,y)=(3,3)$?

Comment: Yes.Nilan give it.Thank you Jack,Happy New year

Comment: @chinamath Happy New Year

Comment: Some more factorisations, not sure if useful: $(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2+x+y)=xy(xy+1)$ and $(x+y+1)(x^2+y^2+1-x-y-xy)=(xy-1)^2-(x+y)^2$. Also, $(x+y+1)(x^2+y^2)=xy(xy+x+y-1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Apologies for the rather long solution.)

---

Write $x = ka$, $y = kb$, with $a, b$ relatively prime.
The equation $(x^2 - y)(y^2 - x) = (x + y)^2$ becomes
$$
\newcommand{\divs}{\; \mid \;}
(ka^2 - b)(kb^2 - a) = (a + b)^2 \tag{1}
$$
Or, rearranged,
$$
(ka + 1)(k b + 1) ab = (a + b)(kb^2 + b + ka^2 + a) \tag{2}
$$
Taking (2) modulo $a$, we get $kb^3 + b^2 \equiv 0$, and
dividing by $b^2$ (which is a unit mod $a$) we get $kb + 1 \equiv 0$.
So $a \divs kb + 1$ and likewise $b \divs ka + 1$.
Let $c = \text{gcd}(ka + 1, kb + 1)$,
$ka + 1 = bcA$, $kb + 1 = acB$ for relatively prime integers $A, B$.
Rewrite (2) as
$$
(bcA)(acB) ab = (a + b)(abcB + abcA)
$$
i.e.
$$
abc A B = (a + b)(A + B). \tag{3}
$$
Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime to $a + b$,
$$
ab \divs A + B \tag{4}
$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime to $A + B$,
$$
AB \divs a + b \tag{5}
$$
Recall the following integer properties:

- If $m \divs n$, then $|m| \le |n|$ OR $n = 0$.
- $|m + n| \le |mn| + 1$ for all $m,n \ne 0$.
  (Follows from triangle inequality and $(|m| - 1)(|n| - 1) \ge 0$.)

From these and (4), (5) we get that
$$
|a + b| \le |ab| + 1 \le |A + B| + 1 \le |AB| + 2 \le |a + b| + 2
$$
unless $A + B = 0$ or $a + b = 0$ or one of $A, B, a, b$ is $0$.

**Case 1:** $\boldsymbol{A + B = 0}$

Since $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime, we conclude WLOG $A = 1$, $B = -1$.
From (3), $abc = 0$.
But $a, b \ne 0$, so $c = 0$.
So $ka + 1 = kb + 1 = 0$.
So $x = ka = -1$ and $y = kb = -1$,
and in this case we get the solution $(x,y) = \boxed{(-1, -1)}$.

**Case 2:** $\boldsymbol{a + b = 0}$

Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, we conclude WLOG $a = 1$, $b = -1$.
From (1),
$(k - 1)(k + 1) = 0$,
so either $k = 1$ or $k = -1$,
giving the solutions $(x,y) = (ka, kb) = (k, -k) = \boxed{(1, -1), (-1, 1)}$.

**Case 3:** $\boldsymbol{abAB = 0}$

From (3) this case implies $0 = (a + b)(A + B)$,
so this case is encompassed in the first two.

**Case 4:** $\boldsymbol{|a + b| \le |ab| + 1 \le |A + B| + 1 \le |AB| + 2 \le |a + b| + 2}$

From the inequality, we conclude that
$$
|a + b| \le |a| + |b| \le |ab| + 1 \le |a + b| + 2 \le |a| + |b| + 2
$$
Therefore,
$$
|ab| + 1 = |a| + |b| + r
$$
where $r \in \{0, 1, 2\}$.
In particular,
$$
(|a| - 1)(|b| - 1) \in \{0, 1, 2\}
$$
We know $a, b \ne 0$.
The first subcase is if $|a| = 1$ or $|b| = 1$ (WLOG $|a| = 1$).
Otherwise, $(|a|, |b|) = (2, 2), (2, 3), \text{ or } (3, 2)$,
Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime,
the first of these is impossible.
Otherwise we may assume $|a| = 2$.
By flipping the sign of $k$, we may assume $a$ is positive.
So we are left with three subcases: $a = 2$ and $b = 3$,
or $a = 2$ and $b = -3$, or $a = 1$.

- **(Case 4a)** $a = 2$, $b = 3$

(1) gives
$(4k - 3)(9k - 2) = 25$,
which has no rational solutions.

- **(Case 4b)** $a = 2$, $b = -3$

(1) gives
$(4k + 4)(9k - 2) = 1$,
which has no rational solutions.

- **(Case 4c)** $a = 1$

From (4), $b \divs A + B$.
By the inequality we are still assuming,
$|A + B| + 1 =$ $|a + b|$, $|a + b| + 1$, or $|a + b| + 2$.
This implies $A + B = \pm(a + b)$
or $A + B \in \pm(a + b) \pm 1$.
With $a = 1$, we have
$A + B = b + 1, -b - 1, b + 2, b, - b, -b - 2$.

*(Case 4c-i)*
If $A + B = b + 1$ or $-b - 1$, then from (4) $b \divs A + B$ so $b = \pm 1$.
$a = 1$ and $b = -1$ implies $a + b = 0$, which we have already covered.
So $a = b = 1$.
Then (2) gives $(k + 1)^2 = 2(2k + 2)$,
so $k = -1$ or $k = 3$.
If $k = -1$ then $(x,y) = (-1, -1)$ which we already found.
If $k = 3$ then we have the solution $(x,y) = \boxed{(3,3)}$.

*(Case 4c-ii)*
If $A + B = b + 2$ or $-b - 2$, then from (4) $b \divs A + B$ so $b \divs 2$.
$b = \pm 1$ is covered in case 4c-i.
So assume $b = \pm 2$.
Then $A + B = 0$ or $\pm 4$.
If $A + B = 0$ this is covered by Case 1.
So assume $|A + B| = 4$.
Rewriting the inequality assumed in Case 4,
$$
|b + 1| \le |b| + 1 \le |A + B| + 1 \le |AB| + 2 \le |b + 1| + 2
$$
The middle term is $|A + B| + 1 = 5$, so $5 \le |b + 1| + 2$,
so $b = 2$.
Returning to (1), we get
$$
(k - 2)(4k - 1) = 9
$$
so $4k^2 - 9k - 7 = 0$,
which has no integer solutions.

*(Case 4c-iii)*
If $A + B = b$ or $-b$,
then write
$A + B = \frac{ka+1}{bc} + \frac{kb+1}{ac}$
so that $ka^2 + a + kb^2 + b = abc(A + B) = \pm b^2 c$.
Then from (2) we get
$$
(k + 1)(bk + 1) = \pm (b + 1) b^2 c
$$
Since no factors of $b$ are shared by $bk + 1$, $b^2 \divs k+1$.
But we also have $k + 1 + kb^2 + b = \pm b^2 c$,
implying $b^2 \divs  b$.
Since $b \ne 0$, $b \in \{-1, 1\}$.
So $(a,b)$ is one of $(1, -1)$ or $(1, 1)$.
But $(a,b) = (1, -1)$ satisfies $a + b = 0$, so was covered by Case 2.
And $(a,b) = (1,1)$ was covered in Case 4c-i.

---

Answer (score 4):

Please don't vote. Just a pictural **comment** to show what
the curve $(x^2-y)(y^2-x)-(x+y)^2=0$ does look like ( : it's an "elbow" ) .

[image]

$\color{red}{Red}$ is positive, $\color{green}{green}$ is negative.
The integer coordinates are yellow lines.
Picture on the right is $\color{blue}{blue}$ rectangle in picture on the left zoomed in $20 \times$ .

Comment: I wouldn't call it "an elbow".

Comment: @VividD: How would you call it then?

Comment: It depends what is around that area! BTW, why don't you zoom out the picture lets say 100 or even 1000 times? I think it will be informative.

Comment: My impression is that the key is not in the small area where all solutions are, but why there is no solution othewise - so I would like really to see how the green area extends for larger x and y. Is there a red island maybe (its "tip" would be point (3,3)?

Comment: I think it would rather be a green lake than red island!

Comment: No, I was wrong, there is neither lake nor island.

Comment: @VividD: Update upon request: picture on the left zoomed out $20 \times$ .

Comment: Miraculous how such a curve can go through infinite outer space
$(|x|,|y|) > (5,5)$ without ever hitting an integer coordinate pair ..

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution. But this shows, we can obtain more solutions than which are given. Suppose $x=y,$ then $$(x^2-x)^2=4x^2$$ has three solutions namely,$$x=y=0, -1, 3.$$ Now suppose $x>y>0,$ if $y=1$ then $$(x^2-1)(1-x^2)=(x+1)^2$$ which has only solution $x=-1.$

Comment: Hello,But other case? $y>1?$

Answer (score 1):

On the LHS the sum of the two factors is nonnegative, so $x^2-y$ and $y^2-x$ cannot be negative at the same time. Hence, if $x+y\ne0$ then both $x^2-y$ and $y^2-x$ must be positive.

If $y^2-x\ge8$ and $x^2-y\ge8$ then 
$$
(x+y)^2 = (x^2-y)(y^2-x) = \\
= \frac{x^2-y}2(y^2-x) +\frac{y^2-x}2(x^2-y) +0 \ge \\
\ge
4(y^2-x) +4(x^2-y) -2(x-y)^2 = \\
= 2(x+y)^2 - 4(x+y); \\
0\le x+y \le 4.
$$

Therefore, all solutions satisfy $0\le x+y\le4$, $1\le x^2-y\le 7$ or $1\le y^2-x\le 7$.
It is a few simple cases and they all lead to finding the integer roots of certain polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: The form of this argument is applicable to any _real_ valued $(x,y)$ ; if so then it cannot be true. Where is the specific integer part ?

Comment: The integer part starts when you solve the cases $x+y=0$, $x+y=1$, ..., $x^2-y=1$, ... $x^2-y=7$ for integers.

Comment: @HandeBruijn No, I think the idea of this is valid.  You will see in my solution as well that a lot of cases amount to seeing if quadratic polynomials have integer coefficients.

Answer (score -1):

Note that your equation is basically

$$-(x^2-y)^2 = (x+y)^2$$

Comment: This is for the equation in the title, but not the equation in the post. Hopefully the OP will clarify which one they intended to ask about.

Comment: Hello,I have edit it,then My problem not this.

Answer (score -1):

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left( {x^2  - y} \right)\left( {y^2  - x} \right) = \left( {x + y} \right)^2  \\ 
  \Leftrightarrow xy\left( {xy - 1} \right) = x^3  + y^3  + x^2  + y^2  \\ 
  \Leftrightarrow xy\left( {xy - 1} \right) = x^2 \left( {1 + x} \right) + y^2 \left( {1 + y} \right) \cdots \left(  *  \right) \\ 
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x = y \\ 
 \left(  *  \right) \Leftrightarrow x^2  - 1 = 2x\left( {1 + x} \right) \\ 
 \left(  *  \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( {1 + x} \right)^2  = 0 \\ 
 \left(  *  \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( {x;y} \right) \in \left\{ {\left( { - 1; - 1} \right)} \right\} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.;\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x =  - y \\ 
 \left(  *  \right) \Leftrightarrow x^2  + 1 = 2x^2  \\ 
 \left(  *  \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( {x;y} \right) \in \left\{ {\left( {1; - 1} \right);\left( { - 1;1} \right)} \right\} \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Comment: In the left bracket, 2nd line, RHS there is a factor $x$ too much: it should be $2(1+x)$.

Comment: I think have other many case except $x=y$ or$-y$